# Torre Hanoi mostrar numero de movimientos en C

Tags: c

No puedo mostrar el numero de movimientos que realiza solo los muestra, alguien me podria orientar, agregue int factorial para que pueda ya que me explicaron que se tenia que agregar ello pero no puedo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int x){
    int rta;
    if(x==0)
        rta=1;
        else
        rta=x*factorial(x-1);
        return rta;
}

void hanoi(int n,int inic,int tmp,int final){
    if(n==1){ 
    printf("\nMueva el disco 1 de la base %c a la base %c",inic ,tmp);  
        return;
    }
    hanoi(n-1,inic,final,tmp);
    printf("\nMover el disco %d de la base %c a la base %c",n,inic,tmp);
    hanoi(n-1,final,tmp,inic);
}

main(){
    int n;
    printf("Digite el numero de discos : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Los movimientos para resolver la torre de Hanoi son : ");
    hanoi(n,'A','C','B');
    printf("\n", factorial);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El título de la pregunta dice C++ pero tanto el código como la etiqueta utilizada apuntan a C... ¿en qué quedamos?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿Qué es eso de **#**? ¿El número total de movimientos tal vez? Te sugiero editar la pregunta de tal forma que todo sea explícito. Elimina las partes interpretables

Comment: @eferion lo acabe de editar

Comment: si factorial es una funcion, que tiene que recibir? y donde la estas llamando?

Comment: @eferion  no lo llamo en ningun lado porque no le entendi y ya intente sin ello pero no se como aplicarlo

Comment: Que cosa es lo que no entendiste? que hace factorial? calcula matematicamente el factorial de un numero. y es la cantidad minima de movimientos para solucionar una torre de hanoi. Ahora, formas de calcular la cantidad de movimientos tenes 2.. esa o contarlos en la funcion recursiva...

Comment: @gbianchi Pero no entiendo cómo contarlo en la función

Comment: @gbianchi El número mínimo de movimientos para resolver una torre de N discos es 2^N-1, y no factorial de N. La función factorial no pinta nada en este ejercicio (salvo que también es recursiva). Supongo que la gracia del ejercicio es contar los movimientos y no simplemente implementar esta fórmula. Para contarlos se puede usar una variable global que se ponga a cero antes de llamar a la función que resuelve hanoi, y que se incrementa cada vez que se mueve un disco (tras el `printf("\nMueva el disco 1 ...")`)

Comment: mi error @abulafia.. se ve que se me mezclaron los algoritmos...

Comment: La verdad no le entiendo mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Has probado con una variable global que vaya incrementandose cada vez que se realiza un movimiento?

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdio.h>

int num=0;

void hanoi(int n,int inic,int tmp,int final){
    if(n==1){ 
    printf("\nMueva el disco 1 de la base %c a la base %c",inic ,tmp);
    num++;
        return;
    }
    hanoi(n-1,inic,final,tmp);
    printf("\nMover el disco %d de la base %c a la base %c",n,inic,tmp);
    num++;
    hanoi(n-1,final,tmp,inic);
}

main(){
    int n;
    printf("Digite el numero de discos : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Los movimientos para resolver la torre de Hanoi son : ");
    hanoi(n,'A','C','B');
    printf("\n %d", num);
    return 0;
}
```